# cocos2dx admob/firebase not woking

Tags: c++, xcode, firebase, admob

I am trying to integrate firebase into my cocos2dx project using the following this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/cpp/cocos2d-x) 
I have install firebase core and firebase admob in pod file. My pod file looks like this:

```
**source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
# Replace "MyGame" with the name of your game.
target 'MyGame-mobile' do
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
end**
```

I have successfully install admob and firebase in my project but I cannot use it in my project. As soon as I'm trying to add this header file into my project it gives me an error which looks like:

```
**The project does not compile. This is the error:
Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group
“OBJC_CLASS$_FIRApp”, referenced from:
“OBJC_CLASS$_FIROptions”, referenced from:
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
I tried to add $(inherited) in Build Settigs > “Other Linker Flags” and these errors disappear, but this persist:
Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**
```